# Ruby threads calling the same function with different arguments

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I am calling the same Ruby function with a number of threads (for example 10 threads). Each thread passes different argument to function.

Example:

```
def test thread_no  
    puts "In thread no." + thread_no.to_s
end

num_threads = 6
threads=[]

for thread_no in 1..num_threads
    puts "Creating thread no. "+thread_no.to_s
    threads << Thread.new{test(thread_no)}
end

threads.each { |thr| thr.join }
```

Output:
 Creating thread no. 1 
 Creating thread no. 2 
 Creating thread no. 3 
 Creating thread no. 4 
 In thread no.4
 Creating thread no. 5 
 Creating thread no. 6 
 In thread no.6
 In thread no.6
 In thread no.6
 In thread no.6
 In thread no.6

Of course I want to get output: In thread no. 1 (2,3,4,5,6) Can I somehow achieve that this would work?

Comment: No idea about ruby, but the same solution as always should apply: use a local variable local_thread_no for thread_no when passing it to the thread constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `for`-loop. In Ruby, it reuses a single variable. 
So all blocks of the thread bodies access the same variable. An this variable is 6 at the end of the loop. The thread itself may start only after the loop has ended.

You can solve this by using the `each`-loops. They are more cleanly implemented, each loop variable exists on its own.

```
(1..num_threads).each do | thread_no |
    puts "Creating thread no. "+thread_no.to_s
    threads << Thread.new{test(thread_no)}
end
```

Unfortunately, `for` loops in ruby are a source of surprises. So it is best to always use `each` loops.

**Addition:**
You an also give `Thread.new` one or several parameters, and these parameters get passed into the thread body block. This way you can make sure that the block uses no vars outside it's own scope, so it also works with for-loops.

```
threads <<  Thread.new(thread_no){|n| test(n) }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Meier already mentioned the reason why `for-end` spits out different result than expected.

`for` loop is language syntax construction, it reuses the same local variable `thread_no` and `thread_no` yields 6 because your `for` loop ends before the last few threads start executing.

In order to get rid of such issue, you can keep a copy of the exact `thread_no` in an another scope - such as -

```
def test thread_no
  puts "In thread no." + thread_no.to_s
end

num_threads = 6
threads     = []

for thread_no in 1..num_threads
  threads << -> (thread_no) { Thread.new { test(thread_no) } }.  (thread_no)
end

threads.each { |thr| thr.join }
```